# Django Social Auth - Importing extra field after user signup

Tags: google-api, google-plus, django-socialauth

I am using Django social auth for the registration and login of my users through Google+ API.
I managed to import extra fields like the URL of the profile picture for instance.

However, I would like to import a new extra field (the language of the user, defined on their G+ profile). How should I proceed to add this field for new user? Can I update it for already existing user (without a new login from their side)?

Sorry if my question is not well written and clear. It's my first post on S.O.

Note : if Omab reads my question > "thanks for Django social auth."

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the user's public profile data so long as you have their Google+ profile id.  Here is an example using the API explorer:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=109716647623830091721&_h=2&